# How to retrieve textbox value and label from form through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie in jquery.

I want to retrieve each textbox value and label from the form. Here I am getting dynamic form in my DOM.

i am triggering form submit even in my DOM something like this and its working..

```
$('.wpc_contact').submit(function(event){
   // here i want textbox value and label
}
```

I have tried with doing **each()** but I didn't get..

```
<form method="POST" id="contact" name="17" class="form-horizontal wpc_contact">
    <fieldset>
        <div id="legend" class="">
            <legend class="">Demo</legend> <div id="alert-message" class="alert hidden"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="input01">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
           <label class="control-label" for="input01">Email</label>
           <div class="controls">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="input-xlarge">
           <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">    
        <div class="controls">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: show your js. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Show the jquery code which you tried.

Comment: i was trying something like var a = $('.wpc_contact').each(function(){
                            alert($(this).attr("class"));
                        }) but didn't help

Comment: Will show the js code, hard to understand what you are centered

Comment: i am triggering form submit event. i updated my code.. please have look

Comment: @user3164335 : Where is jQuery code?

Comment: @Aniket someone edited my question and he has removed i am updating my code

Comment: When you say "retrieve each textbox value and label", what do you actually want to do with them? Do you just need to process them one at a time (e.g., to validate somehow and use the label text in an error message if validation fails), or do you need all of them in an array for use later?

Comment: i want to store it in db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.wpc_contact').submit(function(event){
       // here i want textbox value and label
    $(this).find('input').each(function(){
      alert('text box value:'+$(this).val());
    });
    $(this).find('label').each(function(){
      alert('label text:'+$(this).text());      
    });
});
```

Use of `$(this).find('input')`: It will find all `input text boxes` within the form having class `wpc_contact`. Similarly, `$(this).find('label')`.

**[DEMO Link](http://jsbin.com/EpituDU/4)**

**Requirement to get both label and value together like { label : value } pair, you can try:**

```
$('.wpc_contact').submit(function(event){
  var data = {};
  $('.control-group').each(function(){
    var key = $(this).find('label').text();
    var value = $(this).find('input').val();
    data[key] = value;
  });

  console.log(data);   // data contains label : value pair
});
```

**[DEMO Link2](http://jsbin.com/EpituDU/5)**

Comment: can i get both value and label at a together.. something like Label : value

Comment: @user3164335: No, jQuery doesn't have such selector. You need to apply own logic to make that so.

Comment: @user3164335: You can try something like this for your requirement. http://jsbin.com/EpituDU/5

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery to retrieve the value easily

You have to give in html textbox id='email'
For textbox

eg.

```
$('#email').val('result');
```

For Label

eg.

```
$('#email').text('result');
```

Comment: The OP wants to retrieve all of the input values and associated labels in the form. Are you suggesting that he or she hardcode all of the ids in the JS?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){ 
 // Do your magic here

});
```

If you got the form id:

```
$('#formId input[type="text"]').each(function(){ // Do your magic here });
```

Answer (score 0):

if yo write `$('.wpc_contact').each(function(){ alert($(this).attr("class")); })`

it find all elements that have 'wpc_contact' class but you have one element!!!

you should use with find

```
   $('input').each(function () { alert($(this).attr("class")); })
        $.find('span').each(function () { alert($(this).attr("class")); })
```

if you want value:

```
//text box
$('input').each(function () { alert($(this).val()); })
//label
        $.find('span').each(function () { alert($(this).text()); })
```

Comment: getting class name but how to get value of textbox?

Answer (score 0):

check out this fiddle
you can use

```
$('.wpc_contact input').each(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8DMy4/2/